# Entity Framework Core: one-to-one configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I updated the title to be more relevant.

I have two objects and wish to use EF Core to map them to a database using code first.

I have shortened them a bit for brevity.

```
WeddingDetails
{
    VenueDetails ReceptionDetails { get; set; }
    VenueDeails  WeddingDetails { get; set; }
}

VenueDetails
{
   string StreetAddress { get; set; }
   string PostCode { get; set; }

   public int WeddingDetailsId { get; private set; }
   public WeddingDetails WeddingDetails { get; private set; }
}
```

However when attempting to do the initial migration I am getting the following error from Entity Framework Core:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'WeddingDetails.ReceptionDetails' of type 'VenueDetails'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

The issue is that both receptiondetails and weddingdetails are the same object and this is causing a conflict when Entity Framework Core tries to convert this to a migration, I believe.

Could anyone please help me understand what configuration options I must add to the `OnModelCreating` method using Fluent API/changes I need to make to the objects to smooth out this conflict, thanks.

**Edit**

I actually resolved this by creating a parent class that both reception and wedding derived from, entity framework was then able to differentiate the two objects and kept them in the table using a discriminator.

So I updated it like below

```
VenueDetails
{
   string StreetAddress { get; set; }
   string PostCode { get; set; }
}
WeddingVenueDetails : VenueDetails
{
}
ReceptionVenueDetails : VenueDetails
{
}
```

EF was then able to parse this. The reason I have given the answer to Steve, instead of answering this myself, is that this was not the approach I have decided to go with, but more what he suggested, of actually breaking both of the classes into their own objects to allow for future flexibility and decoupling

Comment: If you make these Owned Entities you won't have to configure the relationships. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationships here are a little bit backwards in terms of where the FK in the relationship will be located. One-to-One relationships are normally associated by PKs on both sides, however EF can be configured to establish a one -to-one relationship using either a one-to-many db-side relationship (FK on Right-side table) or a many-to-one db-side relationships (FK on Left-side table)

For example, given your intended structure /w Wedding and Venues, you want a single Wedding to point to a WeddingVenue and a ReceptionVenue. The next question would be where the FKs should reside. In the case of the WeddingVenue you have set this up as a one-to-many FK with the WeddingID in the Venue table. However, this leaves the ball hanging for how the database is going to figure out the FK for the ReceptionVenue.

You can solve this by swapping to a many-to-one FK where the WeddingVenueId and ReceptionVenueId are part of the Wedding table/entity. If we expose the FK properties as an example in the entity:

```
public class WeddingDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int WeddingDetailsId { get; set; }

    // ... wedding fields...

    public int WeddingVenueId { get; set; }
    public int ReceptionVenueId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WeddingVenueId")]
    public virtual VenueDetails WeddingVenueDetails { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("ReceptionVenueId")]
    public virtual VenueDetails ReceptionVenueDetails { get; set; } 
}
```

Now this technically sets up two many-to-one relationships where the model configuration would look something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WeddingDetails>()
    .HasOne(x => x.WeddingVenueDetails)
    .WithMany();
```

However, we want a WeddingDetails instance on VenueDetails. There is another consideration in that ReceptionVenueDetails is a VenueDetails, that venue will *not* have a WeddingDetails reference, so it probably makes sense to leave this relationship as a many-to-one.

The issue here is that there is nothing stopping the same venue record from:

- Being used for both the Wedding venue and Reception venue.
- Being used as the Wedding and/or Reception venue for a completely different wedding.

The implications of this is that *if* two weddings get linked to the same venue record, updates on one wedding's venue would be reflected on any other weddings linked to that same record. Even if we were to configure EF to expect these to be a one-to-one relationship (which we can using EF Core 5/6 using `HasPrincipalKey`) the fact is that the database FK constraints will always allow two weddings to reference the same Venue record. This forms a Faux one-to-one relationship.

The way to enforce this as a proper one-to-one would be to either have the venue details (for both wedding and reception) embedded in the Wedding table (as an same-table owned type in EF Core) or, establish a WeddingVenueDetails as a one-to-one relationship table. (Either using a standard one-to-one PK relationship or separate table owned type)

What this would look like from entities:

```
public class WeddingDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int WeddingDetailsId { get; set; }

    // ... wedding fields...
    public virtual WeddingVenueDetails WeddingVenueDetails { get; set; }
}

public class WeddingVenueDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int WeddingDetailsId { get; set; }

    string WeddingStreetAddress { get; set; }
    string WeddingPostCode { get; set; }

    string ReceptionStreetAddress { get; set; }
    string ReceptionPostCode { get; set; }

    public virtual WeddingDetails WeddingDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Here WeddingVenueDetails is responsible for both the wedding and reception venue details for a single, specific wedding. We can set up a proper one-to-one relationship between the two:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WeddingDetails>()
    .HasOne(x => x.WeddingVenueDetails) // or OwnsOne()
    .WithOne(x => x.WeddingDetails);
```

In the database table, the WeddingDetailsId serves as the unique PK between both tables and the FK constraint. This enforces a pure one-to-one relationship where any Wedding's venue details can be safely edited independently of possibly affecting any other wedding's venue.

Similarly if you want to separate the WeddingVenue and ReceptionVenue, you can do this, however each would need its own separate table with a WeddingDetailsID as the PK and set up with the same `HasOne`/`WithOne`. (WeddingVenueDetails and ReceptionVenueDetails tables) They cannot be the same VenueDetails table/entity to enforce the pure one-to-one relationship with a WeddingDetails. (There is no such thing as a One-to-Two or One-to-Zero-or-Two relationship.) This may seem non-ideal since these two tables would effectively share the same columns, but from a storage POV it's essentially the same whether 2 records get stored in 1 table, or 1 record gets stored in each of two tables. It also accommodates future flexibility where you may have venue fields that apply only to Weddings or Receptions which can be added to their appropriate table without resorting to conditional Null-able columns. Worst case you end up having to resort to null-able columns that are implied to be required by one or the other with nothing to actually enforce that in the database.  Separate tables are also better if something like the Reception is optional to avoid rows with a bunch of empty columns if in a single Venues table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and well reasoned answer. I believe I will go ahead and split the two venues types out into there own tables, which I was hesitant to do, so thanks for going into detail about that